# Why have a conversion factor of $10 \:\rm mA / 10 \: mV$ instead of $1\:\rm A/1\:V$?

Tags: conventions, si-units, unit-conversion

I’m working with a device that measures current by measuring voltage and then giving current with a conversion factor of $10 \:\rm mA / 10 \:mV$. Why write this instead of $1\:\rm A/1\:V$?

Comment: Is the scale calibrated in $\rm mV$ with a full scale deflection of $10 \,\rm mV$?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that there is any standard for this, but my guess is that they wanted to give you numbers that were roughly related to the accurate range of the device.  It's probably the case that it isn't accurate ~1mA and probably isn't capable of producing 1A.

Answer (score 1):

In these conversion factors, not only the ratio, but also particular values of voltage and current are significant.

In age of old good analogue devices, it would mean the voltage needed for the full scale and current at that voltage.

For digital devices, it means the same for the particular state of the analogue part of the A/D convertor.

Edit: It also means the conversion ratio can be generally different for different scales.